# Sourcetree / Git .ignore file - does not ignore packages folder in solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a setup where SourceTree keeps saying I have a list of uncomitted files. These uncomitted files are various files in my packages folder.

In my .gitignore I am pretty convinced the packages folder is exluded, and this is the setup I use all the time and works. However, this seems pretty strange.

I have a structure with:

/git_project/

In my git_project I have:

/src

.gitignore

In my /src folder, I have my project with the following folders:

[image]

**Screenshot of commits expected:**

[image]

**This is my global Git ignore file:**

```
#ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
```

**This is my local Git file:**

```
# Build Folders (you can keep bin if you'd like, to store dlls and pdbs)
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# mstest test results
TestResults

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.


# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder 
[Ee]xpress

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# NuGet Packages Directory
packages

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
UserData

src/packages


sql
TestResults
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.Cache
ClientBin
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*.dbmdl
Generated_Code #added for RIA/Silverlight projects

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @WiteCastle not at all.. i haven't worked on this project for half a year, and I have not met the problem in future projects.. I have no clue what the problem was. But this this many visitors from Google, I hope someone can leave a clue for all the visitors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firs try to change in your gitignore file

```
packages
```

to

```
packages/
```

then if the files in packages folder are already in git do the following

```
git rm -r --cached packages
git commit
```

it will remove files from git, but not from disk

Comment: Changing the gitignore file did nothing to it, unforunately. Also, the "git rm -r --cached packages" command gives me "fatal: pathspec 'packages' did not match any files"